# URL Rewrite (Windows-сервер)

Tags: php

Переадресация с 
http://site.ru/main.html?cat=1&id=10

на 
http://site.ru/news/view/10 (10 - идентификатор статьи)

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

А какой сервер используется?
И точно имелась в виду переадресация с "http://site.ru/main.html?cat=1&id=10" на "http://site.ru/news/view/10" ?

Например для Апача может быть так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^main.html?cat_name=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)&id=([0-9]+)$ news/$1/view/$2 [L]
```

Категорию придется передавать "по имени", так как вроде нельзя сделать условия в mod_rewrite для сопоставления нужных слов нужным выходным параметрам.

А если наоборот переадресация, то немного иначе:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ main.html?cat_name=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Опять таки ориентироваться придется по имени категории, чтобы сопоставлять ее с нужным номером.
Действие "action" в принципе можно опустить, но мало ли пригодится.

В обоих случаях входная строка должна быть четкой и не менять местами переменные.

Comment: Написано ж... windows-сервер

Comment: я знаю с пяток серверов, которые идут на windows, и это наверняка даже не четверть от всех